# Loading Package pi0. An issue

Tags: r, install.packages, pi0

I'm trying to use package pi0 with dependency true (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pi0/pi0.pdf) in order to create a t.test matrix as reported from inside-r.org.

loading the package I get:

> Library ('pi0') Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,
>   .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    there is no package called
>   ‘qvalue’ Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘pi0’

running this code:

```
set.seed(9992722)
dat=matrix(rnorm(30),3,10)
(pvals=matrix.t.test(dat,1,5,5)) # [1] 0.2112825 0.8366920 0.2891014
(pvals2=apply(dat,1,function(xx)t.test(xx[1:5],xx[6:10],var.equal=TRUE)$p.val))
all.equal(pvals,pvals2) ## TRUE
```

I get:

> Error: could not find function "matrix.t.test"

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `pi0` imports the package `qvalue`. Unfortunately, the package `qvalue` was removed from the CRAN repository. Therefore, you obtain the error message when you try to load the `pi0` package.

From the `DESCRIPTION` file of `pi0`:

> Imports: Matrix (>= 1.0-0), numDeriv, limSolve (>= 1.5.2), rgl,
>           scatterplot3d, **qvalue**, Iso(>= 0.0-5), quadprog (>= 1.5-3),
>           kernlab

The package `qvalue` is now available from Bioconductor. You can use the following commands to install this package.

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("qvalue")
```

Now, you can load the package `pi0`, and your code will run without any problems.

```
library(pi0)
```